# Python: List Comprehension to access multiple lists

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

```
list1 = []
list.append([item1[i], item2[i], item3[i] for i in range(2)])
```

i.e how to populate list1 with `[[item1[0], item2[0], item3[0]],[item1[1], item2[1], item3[1]]]` through list comprehension where item1, item2 item3 are different lists?
Example:

```
item1 = [1,2,3,4]
item2 = [1,4,9,16]
item3 = [1,8,27,64]

# I want list1 =
[[1,1,1],
[2,4,8],
[3,9,27],
[4,16,64]]
# through list comprehension AND APPEND STATEMENT
```

Comment: `list(zip(item1, item2, item3))` ?

Comment: can you specify input and output?

Comment: Could you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Added the example

Comment: According to me you can simply do this using ::  `a = [item1, item2, item3]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add another set of `[]`'s to your code:

```
list1 = []
list1.append([[item1[i], item2[i], item3[i]] for i in range(len(item1))])
```

*Note that this assumes that `item1`, `item2` and `item3` are all the same length*

Alternately, for an exact match of your expected output, use the following:

```
list1 = [[item1[i], item2[i], item3[i]] for i in range(len(item1))]
```

---

*Example data and output*

```
item1 = [1, 2, 3]
item2 = ["A", "B", "C"]
item3 = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
list1 = [[item1[i], item2[i], item3[i]] for i in range(len(item1))]
print(list1)

>>> [[1, 'A', 0.1], [2, 'B', 0.2], [3, 'C', 0.3]]
```

---

Using `.append()`, the list comprehension becomes:

```
for i in range(len(item1)):
    list1.append([item1[i], item2[i], item3[i]])
```

---

However, if you want to use a list comprehension and *still* append the newly created lists onto `list1`, use `+=` rather than `.append()`:

```
list1 += [[item1[i], item2[i], item3[i]] for i in range(len(item1))]
```

`.append()` adds the given item onto the end of the list. `+=` will instead add each sublist individually.

Comment: I also need to use append statement as there are already few rows in the list 1

Comment: Edited my answer to meet the requirements.

Comment: It does the exact job.
But with just append statement and list comprehension, this task doesn't seem possible (without extra for loop)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
list1 = list(zip(item1, item2, item3))
```

this will work until the minimum length of `item1`, `item2`, `item3`. If you want to go longer use `itertools.zip_longest` instead of `zip`.

example with `zip`:

```
item1 = [0,1]
item3 = [2,3]
item2 = [4,5,6]
list1 = list(zip(item1, item2, item3))

[(0, 4, 2), (1, 5, 3)]
```

example with `itertools.zip_longest`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

item1 = [0,1]
item3 = [2,3]
item2 = [4,5,6]
list1 = list(zip_longest(item1, item2, item3))

[(0, 4, 2), (1, 5, 3), (None, 6, None)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If on python 2 just do `zip` without `list`:

```
zip(item1, item2, item3)
```

**Demo:**

```
item1 = [1, 2, 3]
item2 = [4,5,6]
item3 = [7,8,9]
print(zip(item1, item2, item3))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```